ChatGPT for creating Proto Personas and User Stories: What do you think about?

I wanted to start a discussion on using ChatGPT for creating pre-interviews — that is, initial, exploratory conversations aimed at gathering basic information and hypotheses to generate more focused and concrete questions before diving into real user interviews. 
In my recent UX projects, I’ve started using ChatGPT as an initial step to collect relevant information and develop early interview questions. This approach has allowed me to gain a better understanding of user needs and frustrations even before conducting actual user interviews. 
As a result, I was able to create for a concert ticket app a proto-persona and 16 user stories.
I was even able to ask follow-up questions afterwards.
A few thoughts that are on my mind, and that I’d love to ask you:

How do you use ChatGPT in your UX process, especially when preparing
interviews or surveys?
What experiences have you had when creating
"pre-interviews" or initial conversation guides with ChatGPT?
Were there any challenges or unexpected results? How do you handle the
limitations of ChatGPT in this context?

I’m excited to hear your thoughts and experiences! Are there any tips or best practices you can share?
Looking forward to a great discussion! 
Attached you will find two pages of the summary of the interview and the user stories. Just to clarify, I created the summary and the user stories myself, without ChatGPT, because I really enjoy working with the results and want to ensure that everything is analyzed correctly. ✍️
Kind regards,
David




I think your question is more oriented to a forum or chat than to UXSE

Hello Danielillo! :)  I'm new here. You might be right. Could you recommend a suitable forum? That would be very kind.

Quora, Reddit, Discord, any social network or even the chat on this site

Thanks a lot! :)

Thanks again, Danielillo! I am very happy with Reddit. I discovered a UX Research group there and have already received two interesting comments for my  questions.
